# Openshift - cAdvisor - Error

Tags: docker, openshift, cadvisor

I have problem when i want to deploy working well cAdvisor containter in openshift project.

I have a dedicated serviceaccount in openshift project and i add him privileged scc,
then i made some changes in cAdvisor.yaml and try to deploy, containter is working but with an error when i want to go in "Docker Containers" section on webside

Changes i made in cAdvisor.yaml:

```
metadata:
  annotations:    
  openshift.io/scc: privileged

  securityContext:
    runAsUser: 0

  serviceAccount: cadvisor-sa
  serviceAccountName: cadvisor-sa
```

volumes:

```
  volumes:
    - hostPath:
        path: /
      name: rootfs
    - hostPath:
        path: /var/run
      name: var-run
    - hostPath:
        path: /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu
      name: sys
    - hostPath:
        path: /var/lib/docker
      name: docker
```

Error on web:

> failed to get docker info: Got permission denied while trying to
>   connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock:
>   Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/info: dial unix
>   /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied"